# Java - calling a void function without semicolons (;)

Tags: java

I want to call a function without using semicolons, is that possible?

Ex:

```
   void myFunction(){

}
```

I want to call it without using semicolons.

If the function would be something else than void I could write

```
if(myfunction() != null)
{
}
```

How can I do something similar with a void function?

Comment: ...You can't.  Why do you care?

Comment: I need to write a Text file without using semicolons, and I can't find a way to do it without ;, because every class i found that writes a file has a .write function that is void..

Comment: Write your own class with the method which returns boolean and does what you need

Comment: Is a challenge. Write a text file without using semicolons. I can't use PrintWriter.write() because it has no return type, and I need to call that function somehow without using semicolons, or use a different method..

Comment: @Multisync I can't use semicolons in any classes..

Comment: Then please edit your question, and post that "challenge" information as part of the question, as it is key information that changes the entire question.

Comment: This sounds like a task for the [CodeGolf Stack Exchange](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: [You should only ask _practical_, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @TomBlodget I got my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a way of calling a `void` method without using a semi-colon you could use reflection and instead of

```
/*1*/ myObject.myMethod();
/*2*/ myObject.myMethod(arg0, arg1); // myMethod(Type1 arg0, Type2 arg1)
```

you could write

```
// 1
try { 
    if (myObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("myMethod").invoke(myObject) == null) {
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}

// 2
try { 
    if (myObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", Type1.class, Type2.class).invoke(myObject, arg0, arg1) == null) {
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: This is the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to call a function without using semicolons, is that possible?

If I understand your question, yes you can do it by using a unicode semicolon instead of an ASCII one. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello, World!")\u003B // <-- The Java compiler 
             // will make that a semicolon, but it clearly isn't one here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use NIO if you want a non-void `write` function.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html

That said, I don't really understand your question either.

Comment: Can I write a file in only one line of code with this class?

Comment: Depends how large you make your ByteBuffer, but it's definitely doable.

`FileChanel.open("/path/to/file", StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW).write(buffer)`

Comment: It works but the problem is that if I write something , and write again, the text appends to the last one.. how can I clear the text before writing ? Just in one line

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this, never the less in a single line.  It just doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection:

```
class Test {
    public static void functionVoid() {
        System.out.println("void from function");
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
      Method method = Test.class.getMethod("functionVoid");
      Object o = method.invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always return Void ...

```
Void myFunction() {
    return null;
}
```

but what would be the purpose of this ?

Comment: Is a challenge. I Need to write a text file without using semicolons. the PrintWriter class has a .write function that is void..if it would be something else I could do it..but I can't edit the function..

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it ...

Comment: Without using **any** semicolons?  In other words you can't really use Java?

Answer (score 1):

Use groovy which has optional semicolons

Comment: What challenge would it be?